# How to import SharePoint List into Excel VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

Using the following code to import data from SharePoint using Excel VBA, the following error comes up:

> Run-time error '1004':
>    An unexpected error has occurred. Changes to your data cannot be saved

```
Sub ImportSharePointList()

    Dim objMyList As ListObject
    Dim objWksheet As Worksheet
    Dim strSPServer As String


    Const SERVER As String = "<server>:<Port>/Location/Lists"
    Const LISTNAME As String = "{4e78c371-9ff0-410d-86a5-b78499091369}"
    Const VIEWNAME As String = "{C3BD0F82-6BCD-45EF-B43E-DCFEA78067B0}"

    strSPServer = "http://" & SERVER & "/_vti_bin"

    Set objWksheet = Worksheets.Add

    Set objMyList = objWksheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcExternal, _
        Array(strSPServer, LISTNAME, VIEWNAME), False, xlYes, Range("A1"))

End Sub
```

Comment: Taking SERVER string from the URL of "All Site Content" fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work for you.

```
Sub ImportSharePointList()

    Dim objMyList As ListObject
    Dim objWksheet As Worksheet
    Dim strSPServer As String
    Const SERVER As String = "mysite:8003/sites/the-sharepoint-thing/"
    Const LISTNAME As String = "{XXXXXXXXXXXX}"
    Const VIEWNAME As String = "{XXXXXXXXXXXX}"

   ' The SharePoint server URL pointing to
   ' the SharePoint list to import into Excel.
    strSPServer = "http://" & SERVER & "/_vti_bin"
    ' Add a new worksheet to the active workbook.
    Set objWksheet = Worksheets.Add
    ' Add a list range to the newly created worksheet
    ' and populated it with the data from the SharePoint list.
    Set objMyList = objWksheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcExternal, _
        Array(strSPServer, LISTNAME, VIEWNAME), False, , Range("A1"))

End Sub
```